# In Python Plotly is there a bar chart equivilant to histogram binning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly

I'm looking for a way chart, using Plotly, data with date on X axis and a value from a table on the Y axis. Then I want to be able to group the data by week, day, month etc dynamically (i.e with a widget) like in the Plotly Histogram binning example https://plot.ly/python/aggregations/#histogram-binning

Having the same or similar functionality would be acceptable as long as I can have the chart do this dynamically i.e without needing to create a whole new plot

I've tried using the Histogram binning as outlined in the documentations however that doesn't work as histogram relies on counting a rows from a table rather than reading a value straight from a table and using that as the histogram height.

The same functionality doesn't seem to work with bar charts however

My data is arranged like this in a python pandas dataframe

```
    Date           Count
0   2018-01-23     28418
1   2018-08-01     25403
```

The code itself right now is:

```
data = [dict(
  x = final['Date'],
  y = final['Cage Poll [cases]'],
  autobinx = False,
  autobiny = True,
  marker = dict(color = 'rgb(220, 20, 127)'),
  name = 'test',
  type = 'histogram',
  normed = 'True',
  xbins = dict(
    #end = '2016-12-31 12:00',
    size = 'M1',
    #start = '1983-12-31 12:00'
  )
)]

layout = dict(
  paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(240, 240, 240)',
  plot_bgcolor = 'rgb(240, 240, 240)',
  title = '<b>Data sampled from daily reports</b>',
  showlegend = True,
  xaxis = dict(
    title = 'Date',
    type = 'date'
  ),
  yaxis = dict(
    title = 'Count',
    type = 'linear'
  ),
  updatemenus = [dict(
        x = 0.1,
        y = 1.15,
        xref = 'paper',
        yref = 'paper',
        yanchor = 'top',
        active = 1,
        showactive = True,
        buttons = [
        dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', 'D1'],
            label = 'Day',
            method = 'restyle',
        ), dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', 'D7'],
            label = 'Week',
            method = 'restyle',
        ), dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', 'M1'],
            label = 'Month',
            method = 'restyle',
        ), dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', 'M3'],
            label = 'Quarter',
            method = 'restyle',
        ), dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', 'M6'],
            label = 'Half Year',
            method = 'restyle',
        ), dict(
            args = ['xbins.size', 'M12'],
            label = 'Year',
            method = 'restyle',
        )]
  )]
)
fig_dict = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig_dict, validate=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set the `histfunc` argument of your `Histogram` trace to `"sum"` (the default is `"count"`). More info on `histfunc` can be found here: https://plot.ly/python/histograms/